# Unloading the package R6 2.2.0 in R 3.4.4

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using R 3.4.4 in a very controlled environment in my company.

Basically I am having issues loading caret package:

Installation is successful with:
install.packages("caret", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", type= 'binary') - for windows

now when I try to load it, I get the below error:

> library(caret)

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘R6’ 2.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 2.2.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

I have both R6 2.2.0 and R6 2.4.0 installed in my library. However, if I try to uninstall R6 2.2.0, I get the below error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘R6’ version 2.2.0 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘R6’ is imported by ‘mrsdeploy’, ‘CompatibilityAPI’ so cannot be unloaded
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘R6’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It won't unload until everything that imports it is also unloaded, Try unloading `mrsdeploy` and `CompatibilityAPI` first, then unload `R6`, then (as needed) reload them. If either of those two won't unload, you'll need to do this recursively.

Comment: alternatively, is starting a clean R session (i.e., with no packages preloaded) an option? Then `library("caret")` should work ...

Comment: @r2evans Great success! Your solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben Bolker I had tried your solution before posting the question here. Didn't work.

Comment: @r2evans or OP should go ahead and post the comment that worked as an answer ... (FWIW I suspect that your 'clean' session wasn't as clean as you thought, possibly because you had a `.RData` file that reloaded a workspace?)

Answer (score 1):

Package dependencies are to blame: if the package cannot be unloaded because another package has imported some of its functions, then you need to *first* unload that package. In this case, the `mrsdeploy` and `CompatibilityAPI` packages should be removed first. Note that this might be recursive, since anything that has imported anything from either of *those* packages will need to be unloaded.

The suggestion was made to restart with a clean R session, and you said that it did not work. I suggest that you restarted R, but it was not a clean R session: if there is an `.Rdata` file or a project file that automatically loads the previous session's data and/or libraries, then a clean session starts ... pre-cluttered. In that case, you can work around it by starting R manually (perhaps not in RStudio or your preferred IDE) as `R --no-restore`, as that should not restore (well named!) the `.Rdata` file.